# Are Employers Allowed to ask if I am Job Searching?

Tags: employer-relations, employer

My employer asked me if I was job searching, which I am, and I told them that I wasn't.

Are they allowed to ask that?

Comment: Why would you think it was not allowed?

Comment: By "my employer", do you mean your direct manager? Big company or small?  And where are you in the food chain?

Comment: As IDrinkandIKnowThings hints above, of course they're allowed to ask.  But whether or not they're *allowed* to ask seems irrelevant.  The fact is that they *have* already asked, and coming back at them with "Well you're not legally allowed to ask me that" is a great way to sour any relationship you have with the person you're talking to.

Comment: Sidenote: If you divulge that you have indeed been job searching, I would be wary of the next few questions, which will likely be "Has it been on company time?" and "Were you using company resources?"  If you're job-hunting from your personal computer at home: Yeeaah, that's none of their business.  But if you're browsing Monster.com from your company's laptop during your shift, you *bet* it's their business.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings because there are tons of laws restricting what employers are allowed to do. For example, they can't ask if you're pregnant. This varies by country. German is *very* tilted towards the rights of employees.

Comment: Without knowing the exact wording there is of course the possibility that the question was misunderstood. Many years ago a colleague asked me: "Kasper, have you found something new yet?" It happened to be the case that I had a new job at hand, but had not told anybody at my current job about it yet. Naturally that question made me nervous and I acted all confused as I asked back: "what do you mean?" After that the colleague clarified that he was referring to my search for a new apartment.

Comment: I think a better question would be "Are employers allowed to know if I am job searching?"

Comment: @boot4life- Actually that is not true that you are not allowed to ask if they are pregnant.  It opens you up to a potential lawsuit but there is no prohibition in the law about asking the question.

Comment: @boot4life: Of course they _can_ ask whether you're pregnant in Germany even though it's not legal. Since answering "that question is illegal" isn't a good idea, you are allowed to lie, without the company being allowed to hold this against you. So unless you know the company is keen to hire pregnant women, your answer to the question is "no".

Answer (score 24):

If you're in the US, sure they are.  I can't speak for other countries.

There's nothing wrong with the question.  Whether you choose to answer honestly is up to you.  Nobody would blame you for not saying, "Sure! I send out 10 resumes a week!"

What I would do is ask why you were being asked and address that. They may think you're not happy at the company or someone might have started a rumor. I'd squish that as soon as I can. You don't want your employer thinking you're unhappy and prone to leave, even if that's actually the case.

Comment: Actually, I *would* want my employer to know if I was unhappy. After all, if they don't know, they can't fix it. Even if I end up leaving anyway, the remainder of my time there doesn't have to be miserable.

Comment: But if you're not, then this could be a problem.

Answer (score 12):

> My employer asked me if I was job searching, which I am, and I told
>   them that I wasn't.

Okay, so you lied about it. That's not unreasonable.

> Are they allowed to ask that?

Yes they are allowed.

And you are allowed to be honest, to lie, or to say something like "I'd rather not answer."

Something led them to ask this question. Either you are giving off vibes, or word has gotten back to your employer. Check in with what you have been doing recently (telling people at work, taking phone calls from recruiters at work, leaving early, coming in late?) and consider being a bit less obvious if you can.

Comment: But realistically, answering anything other than "No, of course not" will be construed as a yes. And agree with the last paragraph 100% which is what I was trying to say but you said better. :)